# Submit form containing inputs and a List<Model> from view to action using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ipad, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I'm currently building a mobile site for iPad using jquery mobile and ASP.NET MVC 4.  I have two forms on a View - let's call them FormA and FormB.  Each form has user inputs and separate submits.  When FormA submits, I would like to submit FormB as well. (However, the reverse is NOT true - when FormB is submitted by the user, FormA should not submit - which is why they are separate.)

Both Forms use a Model that looks (in part) like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Display(Name = "ID Number:")]
    public string idNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name:")]
    public string fName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Equipment List:")]
    public IEnumerable<EquipmentModel> listOfEquipment { get; set; }

}

public class EquipmentModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Equipment ID:")]
    public string EquipID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Equipment Type:")]
    public string EquipType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Equipment Description:")]
    public string EquipDesc { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Equipment Usage Hours: ")]
    public string EquipUsageHours { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Added By:")]
    public string EquipAddedBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Add Date:")]
    public string EquipAddDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Costkey:")]
    public string EquipCostKey { get; set; }

}
```

FormB looks like this (Basically shows a list of Equipment and the associated usage hours for each piece of equipment.  User is allowed to adjust hours for each piece of equipment by moving a slider):

```
       @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionBName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormB" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <input type="hidden" name="idNumber" value="@Model.idNumber"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="fName" value="@Model.fName">

            if (Model.listOfEquipment != null)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var liEquipModel in Model.listOfEquipment)
                { 
                    <input type="hidden" name="[@i].EquipID" value="@liEquipModel.EquipID"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="[@i].EquipType" value="@liEquipModel.EquipType"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="[@i].EquipDesc" value="@liEquipModel.EquipDesc">  
                    <input type="hidden" name="[@i].EquipAddedBy" value="@liEquipModel.EquipAddedBy">
                    <input type="hidden" name="[@i].EquipAddDate" value="@liEquipModel.EquipAddDate"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="[@i].EquipCostKey" value="@liEquipModel.EquipCostKey"> 
                    DateTime eqAddDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(liEquipModel.EquipAddDate);
                    string eqAddDate = eqAddDateTime.ToString("d");
                    string eqAddTime = eqAddDateTime.ToString("t"); 
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" style="margin-top:5px;"> 
                       <li data-role="list-divider">
                            @woEquipModel.EquipDesc 
                            <span style="float:right;">
                                Equipment ID:&nbsp; <span>@liEquipModel.EquipID</span> 
                            </span> 
                        </li>     
                        <li>
                            <span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold; color:#474747;">


                                <span style="color:#29537E;">Hours:&nbsp;</span>
                            </span>  
                            <span class="ui-li-aside" style="float:right; width:92%; text-align:left; margin-top:-14px;"> 
                                <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; color:#474747;">  
                                    <input type="range"
                                        data-theme="c" 
                                        name="[@i].EquipUsageHours" 
                                        id="slider-1"  
                                        style="font-size: 12px; color:#474747; margin-top:0px;" 
                                        value="@liEquipModel.EquipUsageHours" min="0" max="16" step=".25" 
                                        data-highlight="true" 
                                    />   
                                </span> 
                            </span>
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                    i += 1;
                }
                <div class="ui-grid-solo"> 
                    <div class="ui-block-a" style="float:right; width:30%;">   
                        <input id="btnSaveEquipHours2" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" type="submit" value="Save Hours" />  
                    </div>  
                </div> 
            }
        }
```

The Action that I am submitting FormB to is as follows:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult ActionBName (string idNumber, string fName, List<EquipmentModel> equipList)
{
 //do work to save to database    
}
```

Now, when the user submits FormA, I need to effectively submit FormB.  The tricky part for me is the list of Equipment, which is a model property that is a list of another model.

How do I do this?  I have tried the following jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#FormA').submit(function () {               
       $.post('@Url.Action("ActionBName", "ControllerName")', $("#FormB").serialize())             
    });
});
```

This works on my desktop in Safari and Chrome, but doesn't work on the iPad.

Anybody have any ideas?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the AJAX post is asynchronous, there's a chance that there's a race condition between the AJAX post of FormB and the submitting of FormA; and there would be times (like on iPad) that FormA is submited before FormB.

Try to do them in sequence like this...

```
$(function () {
    var isFormBSubmitted = false;

    $('#FormA').submit(function (e) {   
       if (!isFormBSubmitted) {
           e.preventDefault(); // stop FormA from submitting
           $.post('@Url.Action("ActionBName", "ControllerName")', $("#FormB").serialize())
               .done(function () {
                   isFormBSubmitted = true;
                   $('#FormA').submit(); // submit FormA
               });
       }                         
    });
});
```

Comment: This solved the issue.  Good call.  Thanks @AnthonyChu.